# Do strictly convex Banach spaces guarantee best approximations?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

There is a best approximation theorem for Hilbert spaces.
It states that for any Hilbert space $H$, and for any non-empty, closed and convex subset $A\subset H$, we have for any vector $x\in H$ a unique point $y_0\in A$ which is closest to $x$, i.e. $\|x-y_0\|=\inf_{y\in A}\|x-y\|$.

I expected this to also be true for strictly convex Banach spaces, but I have managed to find a counter example and prove that this is not the case.
I am now wondering if anyone else has proved this before.
On Wikipedia it states: "It also guarantees the uniqueness of a best approximation to an element in X (strictly convex) out of Y (a subspace of X) if indeed such an approximation exists." which leads me to believe this was already known.

I would like to know if anyone else has proved this before and, if so, what their proof was.